# Making an excel readable file?

Tags: excel, fileoutputstream

Is there any information regarding being able to use a toString or a separate method to write to a file and that file can actually be used and opened in excel, therefor creating excel cells etc? Or is this not a well known practice.

Comment: You could write your data to a comma-separated file. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: AFAIK Excel seems to handle HTML tables fine, too (even formatting).

Comment: Submitted my answer (which in my opinion works very well), please review it. If you would like an example of the code to do this, please provide your programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using a Comma Separated Values file, or ***CSV***.
These files can be opened in Excel with columns and rows.

***Example:***

```
Title,Author,FirstPublished,ISBN,
The Communist Manifesto,Marx K.,1887,9780140447576,
The Black Swan,Taleb N.,2008,9780812979183,
When Money Dies,Fergusson A.,1975,9781906964443,
Liar's Poker,Lewis M.,1989,9780340839966,
Paradox,Al-Khalili J.,2012,9780552778060,
Cosmos,Sagan C.,1981,9780349107035,
An Unquiet Mind,Jamison K.,1995,9780330528078,
Principia Mathematica,Russell B.,1913,9781178292992,
Elements,Euclid,-300,9781420934762,
The Principia,Newton I.,1687,9781607962403,
Relativity,Einstein A.,1920,9781891396304,
```

The fields on the first line are the columns, and the fields below are the rows (one on each line).

Comment: Thank you so much! i was unaware, do you know of anyway to add borders to these or no?

Comment: I apologize for the time in which it took me to respond, i am truely sorry! But i do appreciate your answer!

Comment: @StingRay21 I don't think there is, unfortunately.